# How can I install Linux mint to Acer Aspire E1-573

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation

How can I install Linux Mint on Acer Aspire E1-572? I tried the following. On another laptop, I inserted USB stick to my computer. Then I typed sudo unetbootin, chose distribution to be Linux Mint and version 17.3_Live_x64. Then I installed iso to the usb stick and ejected the stick.

On Aspire, first I started it and pressed F2. I typed my password and set boot mode UEFI, Secure Boot Disabled, and boot priority order

1. USB HDD
2. USB FDD
3. USB CDROM
4. ATAPI CDROM
5. Network Boot-IPV4
6. Network Boot-IPV6
7. Windows Boot Manager
8. ubuntuCrucial_CT1050MX300SSD1

Then I put USB stick to computer, pressed F10. Selected Yes to save changes and the computer rebooted itself. But all I got was that Windows tries to install itself. It looks like the computer won't run the installation program from the USB stick. I don't understand what am I doing wrong as the USB stick contains now for example the directory isolinux and setup.exe but I though that unetbootin removes every exe files.

Comment: Please clarify OP: did you successfully installed Mint?

Comment: @mattia.b89 I haven't managed to install Mint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I had somehow messed what partitions the computer reads on startup. I found a way to start computer on Linux by pressing F12 and choosing where to start. Then I modified the partitions and the computer works now.